# Looking for unique numbers in a list of sets

Tags: python, set

I am running my own little experiment and need a little help with the code.

I am creating a list that stores 100 sets in index locations 0-99, with each stored set storing random numbers ranging from 1 to 100 that came from a randomly generated list containing 100 numbers.

For each set of numbers, I use the set() command to filter out any duplicates before appending this set to a list...so basically I have a list of 100 sets which contain numbers between 1-100.

I wrote a little bit of code to check the length of each set - I noticed that my sets were often 60-69 elements in length!  Basically, 1/3 of all numbers is a duplicate.

The code:

```
from random import randint

sets = []

#Generate list containing 100 sets of sets.
#sets contain numbers between 1 and 100 and no duplicates.

for i in range(0, 100):
    nums = []
    for x in range(1, 101):
        nums.append(randint(1, 100))
    sets.append(set(nums))


#print sizes of each set
for i in range(0, len(sets)):
    print(len(sets[i]))


#I now want to create a final set
#using the data stored within all sets to
#see if there is any unique value.
```

So here is the bit I can't get my head around...I want to see if there is a unique number in all of those sets!  What I can't work out is how I go about doing that.

I know I can directly compare a set with another set if they are stored in their own variables...but I can't work out an efficient way of looping through a list of sets and compare them all to create a new set which, I hope, might contain just one unique value!

I have seen this code in the documentation...

```
s.symmetric_difference_update(t)
```

But I can't work out how I might apply that to my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What do you mean by "a unique number"? You mean one number which appears in all of the sets, or a number which is one set but not any of the others, or a number that is not in any of the sets?

Comment: This experiment started when started playing around with sets and noticed that when I loop 100 times and generate a random number between 1-100, quite often I am left with about 60-69 unique values in a set.  I thought it would be fun to see if I could generate 100 sets and compare them to each other.  I wanted to see if there was a way of easily storing each set in a list and then looping through the list, looking at each set to find that unique number.  Obviously the odds are very low with just a range of 1-100...but I thought I would try!!

Comment: What "unique number" are you referring to? Compare the sets to each other how?

Comment: I want to reduce all the sets down to 1 set that contains any numbers that only appear in a single set.  The chances of having any numbers in a range of 1-100 is low but there might be the odd time that actually a number is only generated once.    -- I could simply just keep a count using a dictionary but I wanted to know if there was a way of using sets to remove all duplicates that occur across multiple sets.  I understand that set(list_name) will reduce all duplicates in the list...but I want to do something like set(list_containing_sets) to produce just a final set.  Does this make sense??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Counter dict to count the occurrences keeping values that only have a value of 1 across all sets:

```
from collections import Counter
sets = [{randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)} for i in range(100)]

from itertools import chain

cn = Counter(chain.from_iterable(sets))
unique = [k for k, v in cn.items() if v == 1] # use {} to get  a set
print(unique)
```

For an element to only be unique to any set the count of the element must be 1 across all sets in your list.

If we use a simple example where we add a value definitely outside our range:

```
In [27]: from random import randint
In [28]: from collections import Counter  
In [29]: from itertools import chain
In [30]: sets = [{randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)} for i in range(0, 100)]+ [{1, 2, 102},{3,4,103}]
In [31]: cn = Counter(chain.from_iterable(sets))   
In [32]: unique = [k for k, v in cn.items() if v == 1] 
In [33]: print(unique)
[103, 102]
```

If you want to find the sets that contain any of those elements:

```
In [34]: for st in sets:
   ....:     if not st.isdisjoint(unique):
   ....:            print(st)
   ....:         
set([1, 2, 102])
set([3, 4, 103])
```

For your edited part of the question you can still use a Counter dict using Counter.most_common to get the min and max occurrence:

```
from collections import Counter
cn = Counter()

identified_sets = 0
sets = ({randint(1, MAX) for _ in range(MAX)} for i in range(MAX))

for i, st in enumerate(sets):
    cn.update(st)
    if len(st) < 60 or len(st) > 70:
        print("Set {} Set Length: {}, Duplicates discarded: {:.0f}% *****".
              format(i, len(st), (float((MAX - len(st)))/MAX)*100))
        identified_sets += 1
    else:
        print("Set {} Set Length: {}, Duplicates discarded: {:.0f}%".
              format(i, len(st), (float((MAX - len(st)))/MAX)*100))

#print lowest fequency
comm = cn.most_common()
print("key {} : count {}".format(comm[-1][0],comm[-1][1]))

#print highest frequency
print("key {} : count {}".format(comm[0][0], comm[0][1]))

print("Count of identified sets: {}, {:.0f}%".
      format(identified_sets, (float(identified_sets)/MAX)*100))
```

If you call `random.seed(0)` before you create the sets in this and your own code you will see they both return identical numbers.

Answer (score 0):

well you can do:

```
result = set()
for s in sets:
    result.symmetric_difference_update(s)
```

Comment: Oops this is actually wrong. Look at [what it gives you](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ae/Venn_0110_1001.svg/330px-Venn_0110_1001.svg.png) for three sets - it's not the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the comments I decided to do things a little differently to accomplish my goal.  Essentially, I realised I just wanted to check the frequency of numbers generated by a random number generator after all duplicates have been removed.  I thought I could do this by using sets to remove duplicates and then using a set to remove duplicates found in sets...but this actually doesn't work!!

I also noticed that with 100 sets containing a maximum 100 possible numbers, on average the number of duplicated numbers was around 30-40%.  As you increase the maximum number of sets and, thus the maximum number of numbers generated, the % of duplicated numbers discarded decreases by a clear pattern.

After further investigation you can work out the % of discarded numbers - its all down to probability of hitting the same number once a number has been generated...

Anyway...thanks for the help!

The code updated:

```
from random import randint

sets = []
identified_sets = 0

MAX = 100

for i in range(0, MAX):
    nums = []
    for x in range(1, MAX + 1):
        nums.append(randint(1, MAX))
    nums.sort()
    print("Set %i" % i)
    print(nums)
    print()
    sets.append(set(nums))


for i in range(0, len(sets)):
    #Only relevant when using MAX == 100
    if len(sets[i]) < 60 or len(sets[i]) > 70:
        print("Set %i Set Length: %i, Duplicates discarded: %.0f%s *****" %
              (i, len(sets[i]), (float((MAX - len(sets[i])))/MAX)*100, "%"))
        identified_sets += 1
    else:
        print("Set %i Set Length: %i, Duplicates discarded: %.0f%s" %
              (i, len(sets[i]), (float((MAX - len(sets[i])))/MAX)*100, "%"))


#dictionary of numbers
count = {}
for i in range(1, MAX + 1):
    count[i] = 0

#count occurances of numbers
for s in sets:
    for e in s:
        count[int(e)] += 1


#print lowest fequency
print("key %i : count %i" %
      (min(count, key=count.get), count[min(count, key=count.get)]))

#print highest frequency
print("key %i : count %i" %
      (max(count, key=count.get), count[max(count, key=count.get)]))

#print identified sets <60 and >70 in length as these appear less often
print("Count of identified sets: %i, %.0f%s" %
      (identified_sets, (float(identified_sets)/MAX)*100, "%"))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can keep the reversed matrix as well, which is a mapping from numbers to the set of set indexes where this number has places in. This mapping should be a dict (from numbers to sets) in gerenal, but a simple list of sets can do the trick here.
(We could use Counter too, instead of keeping the whole reversed matrix)

```
from random import randint

sets = [set() for _ in range(100)]
byNum = [set() for _ in range(100)]

#Generate list containing 100 sets of sets.
#sets contain numbers between 1 and 100 and no duplicates.

for setIndex in range(0, 100):
    for numIndex in range(100):
        num = randint(1, 100)
        byNum[num].add(setIndex)
        sets[setIndex].add(num)


#print sizes of each set
for setIndex, _set in enumerate(sets):
    print(setIndex, len(_set))

#I now want to create a final set
#using the data stored within all sets to
#see if there is any unique value.

for num, setIndexes in enumerate(byNum)[1:]:
    if len(setIndexes) == 100:
        print 'number %s has appeared in all the random sets'%num
```